# How to mount volumes in docker release of openFOAM

Tags: docker, openfoam

I am running the docker release of openFOAM.  While running openFOAM, I can't access any of the volumes that I have set up in `/mnt`. I can see them when I run:

```
bash-4.1$ lsblk

NAME                                  MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                                     8:0    0  29.8G  0 disk  
|-sda1                                  8:1    0   200M  0 part  
|-sda2                                  8:2    0   500M  0 part  
`-sda3                                  8:3    0  29.1G  0 part  
  `-luks-c551009c-5ab5-4526-85fa-45105a445734 (dm-0)
                                      253:0    0  29.1G  0 crypt 
    |-korora_a00387863--6-root (dm-1) 253:1    0  26.1G  0 lvm   /etc/passwd
    `-korora_a00387863--6-swap (dm-2) 253:2    0     3G  0 lvm   
sdb                                     8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk  
|-sdb1                                  8:17   0 137.9G  0 part  
|-sdb2                                  8:18   0 158.7G  0 part  
`-sdb3                                  8:19   0 169.2G  0 part  
sdg                                     8:96   1    15G  0 disk  
loop0                                   7:0    0   100G  0 loop  
`-docker-253:1-265037-pool (dm-3)     253:3    0   100G  0 dm    
  `-docker-253:1-265037-10f82f41512f788ec85215e8764cd3c5b0973d548fe4db2fcbcbaf50db6a4b9c (dm-4)
                                      253:4    0    10G  0 dm    /
loop1                                   7:1    0     2G  0 loop  
`-docker-253:1-265037-pool (dm-3)     253:3    0   100G  0 dm    
  `-docker-253:1-265037-10f82f41512f788ec85215e8764cd3c5b0973d548fe4db2fcbcbaf50db6a4b9c (dm-4)
                                      253:4    0    10G  0 dm    /
```

However, none of these show up in `/dev`, so I don't know how to mount the volumes that I want.  It seems like there is a better solution than manually mounting the volume each time I use openFOAM.  Any ideas would be welcome, I don't understand the docker documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't show us exactly what you mean by "volumes set up in `/mnt`", so there will be a lot of guesswork in this answer w/r/t what you're actually trying to do.

If you are trying to mount block devices on your *host* and make them available in your *container*, the normally way you would go about this is:

- Mount the device somewhere on your host (e.g., in `/mnt`)
- Use the `-v` argument to `docker run` to expose that mountpoint inside a container, as in:

  ```
  docker run -v /mnt/volume1:/volume1 alpine sh
  ```

  The above command line would expose `/mnt/volume1` on the host as `/volume1` inside the container.

If you find that you are often running the same container with the same set of volumes, and you're tired of long command lines, just drop the `docker run` command into a shell script, or consider using something like `docker-compose` to help automate things.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  I have a second hard drive with three partitions that are automatically set to mount in /mnt, and just want to be able to access them while I am in openFOAM.  I really don't understand docker - is openFOAM the container?  When I run that command, I get:   docker: Error parsing reference: "/mnt/volume1" is not a valid repository/tag.  I really don't know what I am doing...